# Adding member function in implementation file

Tags: c++, function, class, header, declaration

For homework, I am provided a skeleton class, and told to implement functions from the header in the source file. I am not allowed to change the header, as it will not be turned in, only the implementation file.

However, there is a function I would really like to add to the class ( the operator() function ). How can I declare it to be part of the class without changing the header?

I cannot add a friend function (requires changing the class definition in the header). I cannot just implement it at the top of the source (out-of-line definition does not match...). I cannot redeclare the class at the top (redefinition of class).

Is this even possible? Doing this will save me copying the function body to 4 different places in the code.

FYI, It's an accessor for a circular, doubly linked list. The operator[] is used to access list element elements, and I need an accessor that returns the list element pointer instead. For reference, the operators look like this:

```
// CANT CHANGE THIS, ITS IN THE HEADER
Elem& operator[]( int i ) const;  

// THIS IS WHAT I WANT THOUGH
// ITS NOT IN THE HEADER, SO I CANT USE IT
CNode * CircleList::operator()( int i ) {

    CNode * n = this->header->next;

    if( i < 0 ) {

        while( i < 0 ) {
            n = ( n->prev == this->header ) ? ( n->prev->prev ) : ( n->prev );
            ++i;
        }

    } else if( i > 0 ) {

        while( i > 0 ) {
            n = ( n->next == this->header ) ? ( n->next->next ) : ( n->next );
            --i;
        }

    }

    return n;

}
```

(Most of the ) header in question:

```
#include "point.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef Point Elem;
class CNode{
private:
    Elem elem;
    CNode * next;
    CNode * prev;

    friend class CircleList;
};

class CircleList {
public:
    CircleList();
    ~CircleList();

    Elem& operator[](int i) const;
    void setElemAt (int i, const Elem newElem) const;
private:
    CNode * header;
    int _size;
};
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it is not possible.

Comment: Can you show the header? We can get around this using inheritance if `header` is protected or public. Edit: But that would also require polymorphic use of pointers in the test files.

Comment: You cannot change **anything** at all in the header? Well, too bad...

Comment: Assuming you have all required getters/setters you need in the class, you can always make it a free function that takes a `CircleList&` as a parameter.

Comment: You could make a new class that inherits from the class.

Comment: You could do something evil like `#define private public`before #include'ing the header.  But that would be evil.

Comment: @DanKorn That still wouldn't allow you to add *new* members to the class.

Comment: @Barmar But searching for a unique token at the right position within the class definition would ...

Comment: I think the real answer is that if you think you need to do this, you're going about the whole thing in the wrong way. Why would they say you can't modify the class header, and then assign a project that requires doing so?

Comment: @Barmar That's a good point, at least if we assume the teacher to not just make random constraints.

Comment: This seems like a poor exercise. What you're trying to do actually seems reasonable: you have to write similar code in several functions, and you'd like to encapsulate that in a utility function. If you were really designing the class, you would be able to add private members or friend functions for this purpose. Preventing you from modifying the class specification limits you, so you have to repeat the code. Maybe a macro could be useful, though.

Comment: I can't inherit because the tests will use the base class. Without something like Java interfaces, theres not really a good way to do class based homework in C++ without saying "This is what the header will be, don't change it or everything will break."

#define private public is dirty, but I think it just might work :D

I would use a function that I just pass all the private variables I need into, but they even made the elements of each node private :S

Answer (score 1):

> However, there is a function I would really like to add to the class ( the `operator()` function ). How can I declare it to be part of the class without changing the header?

**Basically, you cannot.**

What you can do is either:

- Derive from the class and add your `operator()` there. Of course this doesn't work when other code has to use the original class with value semantics.
- Wrap the class as a member in your own class, and provide a user defined conversion to the original class. Not pretty, most of the cases.
- Get out black magic, also known as the preprocessor, and wrap the header in your own header [with something like](http://ideone.com/NuyYek) that:

  ```
  #define public \
    public: void operator()(void); public
  // original header content
  struct SomeClass {
    // stuff
    public: // We need this once, otherwise we're screwed
    // other stuff
  };
  // end original header content
  #undef public
  ```

  This obviously breaks ABI compatibility with other code using `SomeClass` via its original header, though.

> Doing this will save me copying the function body to 4 different places in the code.

Why can't you just write a free function `call_it` and instead of `object()` you write `call_it(object)` in these 4 places?

Comment: I think the reason he can't do the last thing is that `call_it()` needs to access private members of the object. He'd need it to be a friend function, but he can't add that.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, yes. What a pity. Or run time polymorphism.